# Writing child instance variables to JSONObject

Tags: java, json, parent-child, org.json

So recently I figured out how to work with JSON in java, and created code that writes, reads and updates information (mostly classes) to and from my JSON database. In my class 'Activity' I have a method that writes the class object to JSON:

```
public void createActivity() {
    File file = database;
    JSONObject newActivity = new JSONObject();
    setRegDate(LocalDate.now());
    try {
        actID = IO.getJsonArray(file, "Activities").length() + 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: Could not set new activity ID.");
    }



    newActivity.put("userID", userID);
    newActivity.put("actDate", actDate);
    newActivity.put("regDate", regDate);
    newActivity.put("actID", actID);
    newActivity.put("description", description);
    newActivity.put("coach", coach);
    

    try {//Writes new user JSONObject to account file.
        IO.putObjInArr(file, newActivity, "Activities");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: Creating activity failed.");
    }
}
```

As the learning process continue, I have now added child-classes to my project. One child-class may contain the instance variables 'distance' and 'time'. There are several child-classes.

Now of course, I do not want to copy the above method to every child-class and there add the specific variables to it. I want all of this centralised in one parent-class.

I wonder, is it possible to somehow loop over all of the possible child-classes' variables, so that I can write those to JSON? Or are child-variables simply not visible to the parent, let alone if I don't specifiy to the parent which variables those might be?

For now, all that I can think of is to put all instance variables of the child class in a hashmap, send them as arguments to Activity.createActivity, and there loop over all the elements of the hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've faced has two main causes:

- The functionality of this method is tightly coupled to the needs of a particular class. And as a consequence can be difficult to reuse in other classes.
- The method itself violates the first principle of SOLID, the [*Single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), which states that a class should have only one reason to change. But there's a whole lot of things happening in `createActivity()`: it reads JSON from a file, it alters the `JSONobject`, it updates the file.

Basically, all pieces of functionality that can be observed `createActivity()` should not be coupled to any class. Instead, this method can be split into several `static` methods, each representing a separate responsibility. And this method can be grouped into a Utility class.

That's how such class might look like:

```
public class JsonUtils {
    
    private JsonUtils() {} // no way and no need to invoke the constructor of this class

    public JSONObject readFromFile(Path path) throws IOException {
        
        String json = Files.readString(path);
        return new JSONObject(json);
    }

    public void updateJsonObject(Map<String, ?> map, JSONObject json) {
        
        map.forEach(json::put);
    }

    public void writeToFile(Path path, JSONObject json) throws IOException {
        
        Files.writeString(path,json.toString());
    }

    public void writeToFile(Path path, JSONObject json, OpenOption... options) throws IOException {
    
        Files.writeString(path,json.toString(), options);
    }
    
    // other methods
}
```

**Note:** `File` class is legacy. The recommended alternative is to use `Path` from NIO API. And if you make use of `Files` utility class from NIO.2 as shown in the example above, it would immensely simplify code of IO-processing methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Right, so I should've gotten this last method out of my Activity class. I had already started creating an IO class, handling input/output and database communication, but somehow I felt the creation of a JSONObject of this specific class, should stay. Good to hear that you disagree, I was in doubt. However, I do feel that the creation of an Activity in the database, which consists of reading, updating and writing JSON, should be bundled together, don't you think? Somehow those 3 steps must be consecutively. I have separated them into getJsonArray() and putObjInArr().

Comment: And to answer my question, you do suggest I use a map then, right?

Comment: @Ontkibbeling *"reading, updating and writing JSON, should be bundled together"* - You can have an operation which require these tree steps, and consequently an **instance method** representing this operation (that's normal). But the whole logic should **not** reside in this method because it becomes hard to test, extend and reuse this functionality (see the link to the Single responsibility principle in the answer). Instead, the **instance method** representing this operation should delegate each step to one of the utility methods.

Comment: @Ontkibbeling I.e. instance method `createActivity()` can make several delegating calls, maybe perform some minor data manipulation in between, but the main logic needs to be split and separated away. That's the way to make the code simple and reusable. Seems like I didn't clarify that properly in the answer.

Comment: Okay, so I was on the right path with my IO.getJsonArray() and IO.putObjInArr(), but I should in addition to that also have the updating of the JSON in a separate method. Just to clarify the bit about the static class: A static class is only allowed when it is nested, right? It is not altogether possible as an outer class? So then I could separate all my JSON-related methods in my IO.java into a nested static JsonUtils class maybe...

Comment: @Ontkibbeling *"you do suggest I use a map"* - `Map` is an easy way to supply several key-value pair as an argument. Note that you can create a Map right on the spot using Java 9 method `Map.of()`. Example: `Map.of("userID",userID,"actDate", actDate)`.

Comment: @Ontkibbeling Regarding `static` modifier on the class, sure, it's only allowed when the class is nested, and I would rather advise placing utility class into a **separate file** (sorry for causing confusion, it was an artifact that I forget to remove).

Comment: One last thing: in _map.forEach(json::put)_ this shorthand notation _json::put_ is new to me. What keywords should I google to learn more about it?

Comment: @Ontkibbeling `json::put` is called [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). It's one of the functional programming features introduced in the language with Java 8. And it's a very broad topic. I would recommend to start with learning about [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and playing with simple examples. In short, both lambdas and method references are meant to represent an action and should conform to so-called *functional interface*.